# AngularJS HTTP Post request failing midstream

Tags: php, angularjs

I have been developing a custom PHP REST Endpoint to interface with a bundle of 4 other systems, and a front-end application to communicate with the Endpoint via GET and POST. Both the API and the Frontend app live on separate domains (systemapi.local and app.local, respectively, with no immediate plan to move them into one domain).

I have an AngularJS call to one of the endpoints for a POST request, essentially doing a login to get an active session. Except when the method itself runs to make the POST call, no POST request is apparently made by my Browser, based on the network output from Chrome.

The manner in which I am sending POST requests is a bit weird, in that i'm sending a urlencoded JSON object in x-www-form-urlencoded. It should be easy enough to gleam from the below code block.

```
//Runs on app.local/index.html
var app = angular.module("FizzBuzzGate", []);

/* Config */
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
  //Reset headers to avoid OPTIONS request (aka preflight)
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
}]);

app.config(['$sceDelegateProvider', function($sceDelegateProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        'self', 
        'http://systemapi.local:9001/**',
        'http://systemapi.local/**'
    ]);
}]);

/* Controllers */
app.controller('FizzBuzzGateLogin', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.login = function() {
    var username = document.getElementById("login_username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("login_password").value;

    requestData = {};
    requestData.method = "login";
    requestData.data = '{"username":"'+username+'"},{"password":"'+password+'"}';
    requestData.dataStr = "method="+requestData.method+"&input_type=json&response_type=json&data="+encodeURIComponent(requestData.data);

    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    if(Boolean(username) && Boolean(password)) {
        $http.post('http://systemapi.local:9001/api/login', requestData.dataStr).success(function(data, status, headers) {
            alert("Request Success!");
        }).error(function(data, status, headers) {
            alert("Error: " + headers);
        });
    } else {
        alert("Fields not populated, please check your fields and try again.");
    }
   };
});

/* Directives */
app.directive("loginForm", function () {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       replace: false,
       templateUrl: "js/templates/login.html" //Basically implements a login form, nothing significant
   };
});
```

In the REST API, I do have CORS settings explictly declared in the headers of every call made:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Orgin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("X-API-Provider: FizzBuzzEnterprises");
```

Still, Angular can never send a successful POST call to the domain. And i'm not sure why. I've made changes in my app to assure that I can do that based on research i've done on Stack Exchange. What am I missing in my code that could fix this issue?

Comment: Any errors in your browser's JavaScript console log?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in fact, I did not set CORS at all in my header. I misspelled "Origin." Fixing that, fixed the issue.